# How can I protect a USB flash drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive, development

I am trying to create a portable development environment on a USB flash drive, I am doing this because I need something ultra portable that I can carry around with me everywhere, I am also a CS student and we have computer lab, so the drive will be a good thing to use in such a scenario.

The platform I work on is Windows, and I will use the drive 99% of the time on Windows computers as well, so cross-compatibility is not an issue for me, at least for now.

I will put VSCode (.zip version) on the drive, along with cmder.

I have one main concern, the computers that I generally plug the drive into are filled with malware and viruses, is there a way, maybe an app, that will protect the drive from such malware?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: What you're asking for is essentially impossible. If you can write to a drive, malware can write to it, period.  No matter how inconvenient it is, never plug your drive into a system you suspect is infected with malware.

Comment: If you can write to it so can malware, no way to protect it if you need to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

They make [flash drives with a physical write protect switch](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb%20stick%20with%20read%20only%20switch). This seems like it might be the safest way and reminds me of the old days with floppy disks; We used to use a write protect on the disk at university for the same reason.

Comment: Are there any other solutions? Development works generally requires reading / writing to the folder where the app is located, for instance installing an extension in VSCode or installing packages using the pip command in Python etc ...

Comment: I can't think of anything that I would trust to work. Maybe a bootable USB drive instead? That way you'd be booting off an uninfected OS. Maybe other people will have alternative ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a drive with a read-only switch, but keep in mind that there is no way to prevent malware on a device from writing to the drive while retaining your own ability to do so.